# Is it possible to crop an image using css and display it as a css background?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I would like to know how to display a part of an image as a css background.

For example: if an image was 500x500 pixels, how would i display the image only showing the top left corner of the image (50x50 starting from 0,0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS `clip` property. If you want to only show the top left corner in a 50px x 50px square you can do

```
position: absolute;
clip: rect(0px, 50px, 50px, 0px);
```

on your background image. As noted, in the comments, this has been deprecated, but there are other options.

You can use the CSS `clip-path` property.

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 10% 0, 10% 10%, 0 10%);
-moz-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 10% 0, 10% 10%, 0 10%);
-o-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 10% 0, 10% 10%, 0 10%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 10% 0, 10% 10%, 0 10%);
```

This will actually always get 10% of the image, so if you only want 50px every time, use

```
-webkit-clip-path: inset(0 450px 450px 0);
-moz-clip-path: inset(0 450px 450px 0);
-o-clip-path: inset(0 450px 450px 0);
clip-path: inset(0 450px 450px 0);
```

You can also wrap the image in a `div` with the class `crop` like this

```
<div class="crop>
    <img src=""/>
</div>
```

and then crop it like this.

```
.crop {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;   
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you would like to adjust the position, you can just adjust the margins on `.crop img`.

Comment: @gidim I've added in an alternative method

Comment: Sorry im fairly new to all of this, could you provide a more detailed example on how to wrap the image in a div with the class crop?

Comment: `clip` is deprecated. `clip-path` is the new recommendation.

Comment: @Nightflare11 I've edited in how to do that, plus another alternative method

Answer (score 0):

CSS background-position lets you do that:

> background-position: -50px -50px;

would be exactly what you described.

Edit:

If you're interested in the center you can use

> background-position: center center;

Or the equivalent:

> background-position: 50% 50%;

Here's a the CSS class with jsfiddle link

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; 
    background-image:     url('http://www.sunderlandecho.com/webimage/1.7367190.1437392150!/image/2890796431.jpg_gen/derivatives/landscape_620/2890796431.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

[jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bBXvt/152/)

Comment: How would you position it so that for example, if I only wanted to display the center part of the image? Similar to when you use context.draw in javascript, you can tell give it the starting x, y positions and width, height to start clipping?

Answer (score 0):

you can try

> background-size: 50px 50px; 
>   background-position:left top;

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/iaezzy/msc3az41/1/

```
-webkit-clip-path: inset(0 450px 450px 0);
-moz-clip-path: inset(0 450px 450px 0);
-o-clip-path: inset(0 450px 450px 0);
clip-path: inset(0 450px 450px 0);
/* values are from-top, from-right, from-bottom, from-left */
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Answer (score 0):

From `[0,0]`

```css
.backImage {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: 500px 500px;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/FNK9ojm.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
 }
.crop {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="backImage crop"></div>
<hr>
<div class="backImage"></div>
```

From the center of the image:

```css
.backImage {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: 500px 500px;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/FNK9ojm.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
 }
.crop {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="backImage crop"></div>
<hr>
<div class="backImage"></div>
```